# Can I reset my Badass Points?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I accidentally upgraded a wrong stat when I leveled up my Badass rank. Now I want to undo it but I couldn't find an option for it. The only thing I found was Enabling/Disabling the bonuses but it doesn't reset them.

Is it possible to redistribute these bonuses and if yes how?

Comment: Is there a limited max? In BL2 you can (effectively) get unlimited BA points, since BA points are shared between chars, but the challenges are individual.  My guess is that you can't reset them since you'll always be able to get more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, there is no way to reset what you have spent your badass points on. The small bonuses they provide don't make that much of a difference anyway. The difference between upgrading one stat over another is not significant, and you can always upgrade that stat you really wanted next time.

Comment: Well, you can upgrade that stat next time *if* it comes up. I've several times hit the wrong one, and had the one I wanted vanish for a few points.

Comment: @BillyMailman Sorry for the late addition. Yes, 5 bonuses that you can upgrade are random, but in a limited way. If some of your bonuses fall behind several levels, the game starts to offer them to you more often. So, if you choose to only upgrade 10 of 14 stats, you're at some point guaranteed to be offered all 4 of your undesirable bonuses plus one random one.

Answer (score 5):

If you remember how much stat bonus value was added and to which stat, you can set the stat bonus to its previous value and then give yourself (or refund) the badass token(s) using the [**Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel Profile Editor**](http://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/borderlands-the-pre-sequel-profile-editor.1223848/). (Make sure to backup profile.bin before editing it.) In the game, you can then redistribute the badass tokens to the stat you want.

[image: Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel Profile Editor screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind having it take a long time, delete the Profile.bin in your saves folder, load up every character so their Badass Points are added, then just assign the ranks again.

Comment: This is probably the most pracitcable way to go and very useful for me, thank you!