# How can I reset my badass rank bonus stats?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

Is there a way to reset your badass ranks on Borderlands The pre-sequel on PC and Steam?

Comment: yes, make a new character.

Comment: No you can't. Your badass ranks are account wide. They allow you to get small percentage based upgrades for playing over time and doing certain things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I reset my Badass Points?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189092/can-i-reset-my-badass-points)

Comment: Note: The questions are slightly different (although the solution is highly similar). This question boils down to "how do I set my level back to zero?", and the [other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189092/can-i-reset-my-badass-points) is "How do I change my level bonus stat choices?"

Comment: Voting to leave this question open. I agree with @aphid that the two questions are different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with the [**Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel Profile Editor**](http://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/borderlands-the-pre-sequel-profile-editor.1223848/). (Make sure to backup profile.bin before editing it.)

[image: Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel Profile Editor screenshot]

Comment: will that work on PC and Steam?

Comment: @Radi Yes. I tried it on the PC version. You only need to open profile.bin on the PC version.